# Google+ quickstart for java oauth 2.0 plugin compilation failure

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am trying to run the [quickstart for Java](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java) which will demonstrate how to authenticate with Google+. I downloaded and followed the instructions.

When I run the step

```
javac -sourcepath src -d bin -classpath "lib/*" src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/Signin.java
```

I get the following error:

```
$ javac -sourcepath src -d bin -classpath "lib/*" src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/Signin.java
src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/Signin.java:87: load(com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory,java.io.InputStream) in com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets cannot be applied to (com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory,java.io.Reader)
      clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, reader);
                                         ^
src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/Signin.java:211: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getSubject()
location: class com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload
        String gplusId = idToken.getPayload().getSubject();
                                             ^
2 errors
```

What is wrong with this example? Should work out of the box.

Also, a Maven project would have been nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub repo had a problem with multiple client library jars being included.  The extra jars have been removed, so the quick-start works correctly now.

If you want to fix your own lib/ directory without redownloading, simply remove the Google jars with the 1.13.1 or 1.13.2 version number.